# Simple inquiry: Does SortedSet<T> have an easy way of finding the median element?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, data-structures

Looking at the documentation on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070(v=vs.110).aspx and I don't see a way. Ideally I would like to be able to find the median (middle element or sum of both middle) of a `SortedSet<int>` in `O(log(n))` time (obviously I know I could do it in `O(n)` time by converting to a list or array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well unfortunately you are right. `SortedSet` does not provide a built-in way to get the median. That is because the underlying data structure of `SortedSet` is a red-black tree. (e.g. see [Red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) on Wikipedia)

Is it possible for you to use an other sort of collection or does it have to be a SortedSet? Otherwise I would suggest to convert it into a list or an array and get the median in O(1) time by accessing the element at index `length+1/2` for an odd value of `length`, or the average of the elements `length/2` and `length/2 - 1`.

Comment: Good answer. An addition, though: I believe a red-black tree could be modified to keep track of the total item count of each node, and if the count is known, that's enough information to access an element by index in O(log(n)) time. `SortedSet` doesn't do this, but a custom implementation that does could be a good fit for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

SortedSet isn't a good way to find the median if you have duplicates in the array 
for example 
[ 5, 2, 2, 7, 3, 7, 9, 0, 2, 3 ]

the median of 9 elements for example should be 2 but you would get only 6 elements and wrong median.

the best way I think is to create your own binary search tree